# How do I resolve this firebase messaging error in the androidmanifest.xml of my flutter application?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was following the steps here, https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#-readme-tab-, to display notifications in my emulator, but I am getting this error in the flutter terminal,

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/steve/Repos/off-top-flutter/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 44; Attribute "name" bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified for element "application".>

Below is my code in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="off_top_mobile"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `android:name` attribute specified twice in your application element:

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

You can have only one.  You probably just want to keep whichever one you started with, and not the one you added.

Comment: Originally I just had , android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication", and the application runs fine, but I wanted to add message notifications from firebase. From the tuttorial, it says to add , android:name=".Application". Is there a way to have both or merge them?

Comment: No, you need at most one. The value of that attribute will not matter for the purpose of messaging.  It should just correctly identify your application class, if you have one.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to solve this @HenryDinh ?